# What can cause the root user in CentOS 6.0 to prevent doing any change in the kernel parameters?

Tags: linux, permissions

In one of my customers Linux box with CentOS 6.0 installed, I found that the user root is prohibited to alter any kernel parameters also editing the /etc/sysctl.conf throws permission denied.

In sudoers list root is given full access.

```
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I was unable to figure out what could prevent root from changing the values.

What can cause the root user to prevent doing any change in the kernel parameters ?

Comment: What error message is given when the root user tries to make a `sysctl` change? `/etc/sudoers` should have NO impact on the root user's privileges.

Comment: I am getting "Operation not permitted" error.

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: I tried both the commands 1. sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core.%e.%p
2. echo "core.%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern and both returned the same error.

Comment: Try `sysctl -p` to see what it returns.

Comment: Yes, even I tried to edit the file /etc/sysctl.conf and run the command sysctl -p but no luck.

Comment: Is selinux or grsec enabled?

Comment: @HampusLi SELinux is not enabled, but not sure about the grsec. I need to contact my customer to get that info. Can you please tell me what else I need to verify ?

Comment: Its worth noting that aside from grsec/selinux, root has permission to do anything it wants already; sudoers has no effect.

Comment: Another idea might be that this is a diskless box using a NFS mount.
So what does `mount` show on this box?

Comment: After googling for a while I could find that if you are using OpenVZ then you cant interact with the kernel or modules directly. I confirmed the same from my customer that they are also using OpenVZ. I am now verifying the same in an OpneVZ environment.